# Why doesn't the exit fullscreen mode button exist in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

**Background:**

I have a live iPad app. in the apple store. I am now developing the iPhone version.
I used MPMoviePlayerController in the Ipad version. But, I had to use the MPMoviePlayer**View**Controller for the Iphone version to solve some orientation problem.

Problem:
In the iPad version when the user go to the fullscreen he will have the **Done** and the **Exit Fullscreen** Buttons.
In the iPhone version the Exit Fullscreen Button does not appear. Only the Done button is appearing.

**Note 1:**
Using the MPMoviePlayerController and not the ViewController won't solve the problem for the iPhone.

**Note 2:**
The done button will pause the movie while the exit button will keep the movie playing in the other view I have.

Any ideas, please help.

Comment: Have you tried to make an universal app from the ipad version already?

Comment: yes it is a universal app. so?

Comment: I wonder why you needed a different controller on the iphone. What are the orientation problems?

Comment: 1. I told you that the MPMoviePlayer won't solve the problem any way. 2. I wonna override the orientation methods inside the player to prevent portrait orientation on fullscreen. I looked deep on this. I am sure. and I can't access it from the MPMoviePlayerController only from the MPMoviePlayerViewController

Comment: You can specify the supported orientations in the project settings for both devices.

Comment: in the Iphone i have some portrait windows. so I set the supported orientations to portrait and landscape. removing the portrait will solve the problem for the player. but what about other windows. it won't work. :)

Comment: It must be done in the root view controller. Set a flag when you start playing, then implement the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration` method where you can control the new orientation.

Comment: I solved the orientation thing by adding a notification observer on device did rotate. when that triggered I did: [player.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:lastOrientation animated:NO];
        [player.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO]; but thats was not my question!